# User Profile Synchronization Service status sits in “Starting” status for sometime and finally status gets changed to “Stopped”

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, userprofile-sync

I have created a User Profile Service Application in SharePoint 2010. But when I try to start the User profile synchronization service it sits in “Starting” status for sometime and finally status gets changed to “Stopped”.

- I am using Farm account to start User profile synchronization service.
- The farm account is member of local administrator group
- Service account used to run User profile synchronization service is also a member of local administrator group.

I have created a new/fresh SharePoint 2010 server and I am able to start the service. I have stopped the service for testing and then trying to start again and I am seeing the same issue in this new server as well now. If I stop the User Profile Synchronization service from Central Administration, are there any configurations I need to do before attempting to start the service again?

Comment: When it comes to UPS, you need Spence Harbar. Read every line, and follow the instruction. I mean read and configure without skipping steps or browsing through this lengthy content. It works every time, the 25 times I have used this guide in SP2010, SP2013 and SP2016. See http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Comment: Check User Profile Synchronization Service checklist at [User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on 'Starting'](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/14/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/) also check  [USER PROFILE SYNCHRONIZATION SERVICE STARTING THEN STOPPED IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to troubleshoot your issue:

1. Check the Certificates store on the server that runs the User Profile Synchronisation Service and delete all the ForefrontIdentityManager certificates.
2. Set the FIM Services to run as Local System.
3. Check Central Administration for the ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob and delete any running jobs.
4. Provision the User Profile Service using Central Administration.

More information refer to this [article](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/01/user-profile-service-stuck-on-starting/)